# Simplify $\frac{(1-\cos x)}{\sin x} + \frac{\sin x}{(1-\cos x)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

**Simplify $$\dfrac{(1-\cos x)}{\sin x} + \dfrac{\sin x}{(1-\cos x)}$$**

Are the steps taken for the correct solution accurate as shown below? And if not, what are the correct steps and solutions?

1. $(\frac{-\sin x}{\sin x}) + (\frac{\sin x}{-\sin x})$
2. $-1 - 1 = -2$

Comment: You replaced $1-\cos x$ with $-\sin x$, but you cannot do that because they are *not* identical.  Rather use the identity of $1-\cos^2 x= \sin^2 x$.

Comment: The person who edited my post copied the question wrong. It's not cross-multiply, it's addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a common denominator:

$$
\frac{1-\cos x}{\sin x} + \frac{\sin x}{1-\cos x} \;\; =\;\; \frac{1-\cos x}{\sin x}\cdot \frac{1-\cos x}{1-\cos x} + \frac{\sin x}{1-\cos x}\cdot \frac{\sin x}{\sin x}.
$$

You'll probably need the Pythagorean identity in simplifying this: $\sin^2x + \cos^2x = 1$.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: An editor edited my question wrong. It's not a cross-multiply, it's addition.

Comment: @fauna Got it.  Edited my answer.

Comment: The original version had $\div$ in it, and not addition.

Comment: @AndrewChin The OP said in multiple places that it's supposed to be addition.

Comment: @AndrewChin The division sign was for fraction bars, since did not know how to format fractions in original version.

Answer (score 0):

No. We can use 
$$s^2+c^2=1$$
to bring to second part in form
$$ \dfrac {s}{1-c}=\dfrac {1+c} {s}$$
So on a common denominator given fractions simplify to:
$$\dfrac {1-c + 1+c }{s} =\dfrac{2}{s}$$